# Calculating nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, calculation

It is becoming clear to me that apparently I have no idea what I am doing :( just a casual biting more than than I can chew.

The result I want to get is:

```
People bought 9 of sirni.
Shop stock increased 10 of pizza.
```

I also have unresolved reference burek_name error but I thought to address that as a secondary challenge once I break through calculation. And as a third challenge I am aware I will have to address the numbers into absolute value instead of +-. Please help me with nudging me into the right direction with calculation as I am stuck!

Thank you for your time reading!

```
burek_dict_0 = {"bureks": {
    "1": {
        "burek_name": "sirni",
        "burek_price": 1.8,
        "burek_available": 10
    },
    "2": {
        "burek_name": "mesni",
        "burek_price": 2,
        "burek_available": 10
    },
    "3": {
        "burek_name": "pizza",
        "burek_price": 1.9,
        "burek_available": 10
    }
}}

burek_dict_1 = {"bureks": {
    "1": {
        "burek_name": "sirni",
        "burek_price": 1.8,
        "burek_available": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "burek_name": "mesni",
        "burek_price": 2,
        "burek_available": 10
    },
    "3": {
        "burek_name": "pizza",
        "burek_price": 1.9,
        "burek_available": 20
    }
}}


def get_burek_avail():
    global burek_dict_0
    global burek_dict_1
    burek_available_0 = ""
    burek_available_1 = ""

    while True:

        for bureks, key in burek_dict_0.items():
            for key, burek_available in bureks.items():
                burek_available_0 = key['burek_available']

        for bureks, key in burek_dict_1.items():
            for key, burek_available in bureks.items():
                burek_available_1 = key['burek_available']

        if burek_available_0 - burek_available_1 > 0:
            sold = burek_available_0 - burek_available_1
            print(f"People bought {sold} of {burek_name}. ")

        if burek_available_0 - burek_available_1 < 0:
            sold = burek_available_0 - burek_available_1
            print(f"Shop stock increased {sold} of {burek_name}. ")
```

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
burek_dict_0 = {"bureks": {
    "1": {
        "burek_name": "sirni",
        "burek_price": 1.8,
        "burek_available": 10
    },
    "2": {
        "burek_name": "mesni",
        "burek_price": 2,
        "burek_available": 10
    },
    "3": {
        "burek_name": "pizza",
        "burek_price": 1.9,
        "burek_available": 10
    }
}}

burek_dict_1 = {"bureks": {
    "1": {
        "burek_name": "sirni",
        "burek_price": 1.8,
        "burek_available": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "burek_name": "mesni",
        "burek_price": 2,
        "burek_available": 10
    },
    "3": {
        "burek_name": "pizza",
        "burek_price": 1.9,
        "burek_available": 20
    }
}}


def get_burek_avail():
    burek_available_0 = 0
    burek_available_1 = 0

    bureks_0 = burek_dict_0['bureks'].values()
    bureks_1 = burek_dict_1['bureks'].values()
    
    for init, end in zip(bureks_0, bureks_1):
        burek_available_0 = init['burek_available']
        burek_available_1 = end['burek_available']
        burek_name = init['burek_name']

        if burek_available_0 > burek_available_1:
            sold = burek_available_0 - burek_available_1
            print(f"People bought {sold} of {burek_name}. ")

        if burek_available_0 < burek_available_1:
            sold = burek_available_1 - burek_available_0
            print(f"Shop stock increased {sold} of {burek_name}. ")
```

I used `zip()` to pair the values of the two dictionaries together.

Here's the output:

```
>>> get_burek_avail()
People bought 9 of sirni. 
Shop stock increased 10 of pizza.
```